# Visual Studio ignoring breakpoints

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

Visual Studio is ignoring my breakpoints. I don't know if it makes a difference but this is happening in Web API. I know it's passing over my code because I can put `Console.WriteLine('FOO');` in and it shows up. But it passes over my breakpoints like they aren't even there. I added `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();` and that gives me this dialog even though I opened Visual Studio as an administrator.

[image]

I'm starting the Web API project directly. That is, I'm not starting a project that uses Web API and therefore need to right click Solution > Startup Projects and set Web API to start. The project is in debug mode. I've cleaned my solution, restarted IIS, and closed and reopened Visual Studio.

Also, I can open other projects, like an ASP.NET MVC app, and the breakpoints work fine there. It's just Web API. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using any libraries? Usually when you modify a library you have to rebuild the projects (F6) for it to all work again.

Comment: I've rebuilt the solution several times if that's what you mean.

Comment: FIXED - I restarted my computer and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart your computer.

I don't know what the exact cause was but after trying everything else I restarted and now it works.

Also, I had to run it from another project. If I debug the Web API project it doesn't hit the breakpoints but if I debug from the Web UI project (Web API is part of that solution) it works.

**edit**

And actually that only worked like one time. I ended up including Web API in startup projects and also copying the dll and pdb to c:\mySymbols on each build via post build commands copy c:\path\the.dll c:\mySmbols\the.dll and then going to debug > options > debugging > symbols and adding the path to c:\mySymbols to the list.

**edit**

Another thing is I was trying to use a custom request validator via

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="4.5" executionTimeout="300" maxRequestLength="51200" requestValidationType="MyProj.App_Code.CustomRequestValidator" />
```

and that definitely breaks it. So I had to take that out too (at least until I figure this problem out).

I'm not sure which, if any of these things did the trick but it is working now.